# jasperreports Out of memory after lots of reports

Tags: java, jasper-reports, out-of-memory, jasperserver

I would avoid an Out of Memory exception in my JasperReport Server.
please, help me.

EDIT 29/08/2015
I'm using JasperReport server 6.1 on Ubuntu 14.04, java 8
Same result --- DETAILS BELOW

I wrote a java code to download (store in local files) multiple pdf reports from my instance of JasperReport Server.
It works well for about 600 reports, after that it produce an error 500.
In the JasperServer log file I see an Out of memory exception.

maybe there is an error in my code? don't think so.
Instead I think there is a memory leak in the jasperReport server.

here you can see my java code (class ga.system.jasperserver.ReportExtractor)

```
    for (ReportParameters aReportParams : listOfReportParameters)
    {
        String filename = "report-"+aReportParams.getParameter1()+ ".PDF";
        jasperreport_url = combineParamsIntoJasperserverUrl(aReportParams);
        URL website = new URL(jasperreport_url);
        ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(destPath+"/" +filename);
        fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
        fos.close();
        rbc.close();
    }
```

here you can see a snippet of the exception I get

> java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: http://myjasperserverurl/jasperserver/rest_v2/reports/TestDir/TestReport.pdf?j_username=xxx&j_password=xxx&PARAMETER1=9734&PARAMETER2=0&PARAMETER3=815G21
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
>       at java.net.URL.openStream(Unknown Source)
>       at ga.system.jasperserver.ReportExtractor.extract(ReportExtractor.java:102)
>   ...
>   ...
>   ...

Here you can see the log in JasperReport Server (catalina.out snippet)

```
 2015-08-17 18:16:17,091 ERROR RunReportServiceImpl,pool-5-thread-66:511 - caught Throwable exception: Java heap space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2271)
        at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:113)
        at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93)
        at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:140)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
        at com.lowagie.text.pdf.OutputStreamCounter.flush(Unknown Source)
        at com.lowagie.text.DocWriter.close(Unknown Source)
        at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter.close(Unknown Source)
        at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfDocument.close(Unknown Source)
        at com.lowagie.text.Document.close(Unknown Source)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReportToStream(JRPdfExporter.java:815)
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReport(JRPdfExporter.java:513)
        at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl.exportToPdf(EngineServiceImpl.java:559)
        at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.remote.exporters.PdfExporter.exportReport(PdfExporter.java:98)
        at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.remote.services.impl.ReportExecutorImpl.exportReport(ReportExecutorImpl.java:177)
        at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.remote.services.impl.RunReportServiceImpl.generateReportOutput(RunReportServiceImpl.java:478)
        at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.remote.services.impl.RunReportServiceImpl.executeExport(RunReportServiceImpl.java:378)
        at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.remote.services.impl.RunReportServiceImpl$2.run(RunReportServiceImpl.java:343)
        at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.logging.util.LoggableExecutorService$1.run(LoggableExecutorService.java:59)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Virtualizer used in my server (applicationContext.xml snippet)

```
<bean id="fileVirtualizerFactory" class="com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.common.service.impl.FileVirtualizerFactory">
    <property name="maxSize" value="3000"></property>
    <property name="directory" value="${java.io.tmpdir}"></property>
</bean>
```

I'm using JasperReport server 5.6.0 on Ubuntu 14.04 (trusty), java 8

EDIT 29/08/2015
new test using JasperReport server 6.1 on Ubuntu 14.04, java 8
Same result, freshly installed server, after 580 pdf produced the server hangs showing this message (read last line: "Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space"):

> org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not initialize
>   lazy properties:
>   [com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.metadata.common.service.impl.hibernate.persistent.RepoFileResource#8448]
>   at
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:126)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:114)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.initializeLazyPropertiesFromDatastore(AbstractEntityPersister.java:831)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.initializeLazyProperty(AbstractEntityPersister.java:771)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.intercept.AbstractFieldInterceptor.intercept(AbstractFieldInterceptor.java:97)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.intercept.cglib.FieldInterceptorImpl.readObject(FieldInterceptorImpl.java:98)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.metadata.common.service.impl.hibernate.persistent.RepoFileResource.$cglib_read_data(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.metadata.common.service.impl.hibernate.persistent.RepoFileResource.getData(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.metadata.common.service.impl.hibernate.persistent.RepoFileResource.copyData(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.metadata.common.service.impl.hibernate.HibernateRepositoryServiceImpl$22.execute(HibernateRepositoryServiceImpl.java:1420)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.metadata.common.service.impl.HibernateDaoImpl.executeCallback(HibernateDaoImpl.java:56)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.metadata.common.service.impl.hibernate.HibernateRepositoryServiceImpl.getResourceData(HibernateRepositoryServiceImpl.java:1414)
>   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor337.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) at
>   org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:319)
>   at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
>   at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
>   at
>   org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
>   at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
>   at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
>   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy32.getResourceData(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor337.invoke(Unknown Source) at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) at
>   org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:319)
>   at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
>   at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.metadata.user.service.impl.PermissionsPrefetcher.invoke(PermissionsPrefetcher.java:79)
>   at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.metadata.user.service.impl.PermissionsPrefetcher.invoke(PermissionsPrefetcher.java:79)
>   at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.intercept.method.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:66)
>   at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.intercept.method.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:66)
>   at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
>   at
>   org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
>   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy38.getResourceData(Unknown Source) at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.util.repo.RepositoryConnection.getInputStream(RepositoryConnection.java:114)
>   at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1037) at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.getInputStream(JRLoader.java:298)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.repo.DefaultRepositoryService.getInputStream(DefaultRepositoryService.java:100)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.repo.InputStreamPersistenceService.load(InputStreamPersistenceService.java:48)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.repo.DefaultRepositoryService.getResource(DefaultRepositoryService.java:155)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.repo.RepositoryUtil.findInputStream(RepositoryUtil.java:176)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.repo.RepositoryUtil.getBytesFromLocation(RepositoryUtil.java:192)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.RenderableUtil.getRenderable(RenderableUtil.java:121)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillImage.evaluateImage(JRFillImage.java:536)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillImage.evaluate(JRFillImage.java:472)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluate(JRFillElementContainer.java:259)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.evaluate(JRFillBand.java:456)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillBackground(JRVerticalFiller.java:1846)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:288)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:152)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:963)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseFillHandle$ReportFiller.run(BaseFillHandle.java:120)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl$SynchronousExecutor.execute(EngineServiceImpl.java:886)
>   at
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseFillHandle.startFill(BaseFillHandle.java:165)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl.fillReport(EngineServiceImpl.java:1804)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl$SynchronousReportFiller.fillReport(EngineServiceImpl.java:790)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl.fillReport(EngineServiceImpl.java:1731)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl$ReportFill.runWithDataSource(EngineServiceImpl.java:1086)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl$ReportFill.runReport(EngineServiceImpl.java:1015)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl$ReportRunnable.run(EngineServiceImpl.java:908)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl$SynchronousExecutor.execute(EngineServiceImpl.java:886)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl.fillReport(EngineServiceImpl.java:607)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl.executeReportUnitRequest(EngineServiceImpl.java:1937)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.domain.impl.ReportUnitRequest.execute(ReportUnitRequest.java:67)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl.execute(EngineServiceImpl.java:497)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.remote.services.impl.ReportExecutorImpl$GenericRunReportStrategy.runReport(ReportExecutorImpl.java:225)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.remote.services.impl.ReportExecutorImpl.runReport(ReportExecutorImpl.java:127)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.remote.services.impl.RunReportServiceImpl$1.run(RunReportServiceImpl.java:230)
>   at
>   com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.logging.util.LoggableExecutorService$1.run(LoggableExecutorService.java:59)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) Caused by:
>   org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Fine memoria scaricando i risultati
>   della query. at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1816)
>   at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
>   at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:510)
>   at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:386)
>   at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:271) at
>   org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
>   at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.initializeLazyPropertiesFromDatastore(AbstractEntityPersister.java:802)
>   ... 73 more 
>   Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

feel free to ask for details you need!
Please help
Thanks

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, did you ever track it down?  Eclipse MAT says that GC root is

Comment: @Massimiliano Did you find any solution? We too facing same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Memory management is a common problem with Jasper. You want to use a Jasper [Virtualizer](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/virtualizers-jasperreports) to cut down on the heap load.

Comment: do you think it is an eccessive heap load?
I'm doing many different separated calls (report generation), at the end of the call Jasper must frees memory ... even if I make a single call.
Each of the generated reports is 3 or 4 pages and does not justify an out of memory ...

Comment: Jasper is notorious for poor memory management - memory is not freed once the report is ready. You will have to use either Jasper virtualizers or increase the heap size until you no longer run into OutOfMemory. You may also try upgrading the Jasper version to the latest - the library has seen many improvements in memory usage.

Comment: I'm using the File Virtualizer, text edited to add this information

Comment: need time to install, import all my reports and try the new server version. Tthanks for your help

Comment: installed, tested, ... negative response. Adding details into question

Answer (score 0):

I am having the exact same problem.  Lots of fast running, small reports eventually wipe out memory.  Eclipse MAT says that shortest path to GC Root is:

[image: No Paths To GC Root I can do anything about...]

[image: Here is the Leak Suspect Report:]

Comment: Nice research, though this is not an answer. Have you found a solution since then?

Comment: Ultimately this turned out to be a corrupt .jasper file. Regenerating the jasper file for the main report and all subreports fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately this turned out to be a corrupt .jasper file.  Regenerating the jasper file for the main report and all subreports fixed the issue for me.